# Math Processing Error pops out when line is too long.

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I write long computation I break the line with \\ symbol like in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455031/basic-tensor-derivation/1455177#1455177). However something has changed and now Math Processing Error pops out with such syntax. I see that between double dolar marks I can not write too many symbols.

Can you change it back, so that \\ will work again? And how should I write long computations now? By creating new double dolar marks?

**EDIT** I have just checked and it seems to be the problem with new Mozilla, cause everething looks fine in Chrome. However I still do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using the `\\ ` syntax within the `align` or `aligned` environments, or just in the default displaymath context?

Comment: @hardmath I use default. I believe you can check it yourself, by clicking edit button in the answer in the link. It suprises me that it looks ok in Chrome, but spits Error in Firefox. Even though I use Firefox all the time. I guessed it has to do with this MathJax update, but now I am not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm mostly a Chrome user, both on my desktop and laptop, and on my smartphone.  Nonetheless I've added the `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` to your equation chain, and await your judgement whether this is an improvement.

Comment: @hardmath I think this is not a good idea to make such edit, cause still I have the same problem with other users posts. For example I still see Error in [Abdelmajits answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128195/lie-derivative-of-a-vector-field-equals-the-lie-bracket/1918410#1918410). Besides now after the edit it looks inelegant. Everything is shift to the right. I wonder if other Firefox users have this issue.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem; your original, unedited answer works fine for me in Firefox.  Due to the recent switch to MathJax v2.7-beta, you may have some cached v2.6.1 files that are causing the problem.  Try clearing your cache and restarting the browser.  That may resolve the problem for you.

Comment: @DavideCervone I admire your. It worked! Mayby post an answer and I accept it in case anyone has simmilar problem.

Comment: @FallenApart:  Please feel free to roll back my edit, which was made primarily for your differential diagnosis and to illustrate for you the `align` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the problem; your original, unedited answer works fine for me in Firefox. Due to the recent switch to MathJax v2.7-beta, you may have some cached v2.6.1 files that are causing the problem. Try clearing your cache and restarting the browser. That should resolve the problem for you.